# How to dynamically resize ContentPane inside BorderContainer (dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

Could someone help me?
I'd like to implement auto-resize of ContentPane that placed inside BorderContainer.
Here is the simple test case: http://jsfiddle.net/3dft2/1/
In this case I have TitlePane inside ContentPane (but in general, it may be any content inside). When I click on TitlePane (and it opens => content height changes) I'd like to auto-resize ContentPane accordingly content size. I.e. I'd like to move the splitter.
How to archieve this? How to watch content sizes (no matter what kind of content) and auto-resize ContentPane if this sizes was changed?

test-case:

```
dojo.require("dijit.TitlePane");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
dojo.ready(function() {
     // create a BorderContainer as the top widget in the hierarchy
    var bc = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({
        style: "height: 300px; width: 500px;"
    });

    var TitlePane = new dijit.TitlePane({
        title: 'title pane',
        open: false,
        content: "Collapse me!"        
    });

    // create a ContentPane as the left pane in the BorderContainer
    var cp1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        region: "top",
        style: "width: 100px",
        content: TitlePane,
        splitter: "true"
    });
    bc.addChild(cp1);

    // create a ContentPane as the center pane in the BorderContainer
    var cp2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
        region: "center",
        content: "how are you?"
    });
    bc.addChild(cp2);

    // put the top level widget into the document, and then call startup()
    bc.placeAt(document.body);
    bc.startup();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the title pane is collapsed, decrease the height accordingly by using it's style property. And when it expanded, you can set add the height as required. Anyways, there are already methods for that. We just need to add the code for setting the height.
Maybe, if you get scrollbars and that is your problem, then increase the Border container's height. Content Pane's are by default auto re-sizable.